# Python tkinter button event

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import random

# GUI
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Hangman")
window.geometry("640x400+100+100")
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()
button_animal = tkinter.Button(frame)
button_animal['text'] = "Animal"
button_animal['background'] = 'yellow'
button_animal.pack()
button_capital = tkinter.Button(frame)
button_capital['text'] = "Capital"
button_capital['background'] = 'blue'
button_capital.pack()
```

This is what I wrote so far, what am I supposed to do to make the button to make event happens?

if I click animal, it should play a game, but I am not sure how to do at first.

Comment: You should take a look at some documentation about tkinter (for instance [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html). Buttons have a `command` option to execute a function when clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `command` parameter to your button initialization. You can find more information in here [tkinter button widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Basically, you can bind your button to function in two ways:

```
button_animal = tkinter.Button(frame, command=your_function)
```

or if your function requires arguments, you can use `lambda`, like:

```
button_animal = tkinter.Button(frame, command=lambda : your_function(arg))
```

If you want to bind multiple function, you can do following:

```
button_animal = tkinter.Button(frame, command=lambda :[funct1(arg),funct2(arg)])
```